# Database log file corruption in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, corruption

I've been going through data corruption from last 2 days in row that .ldf getting corrupted and I've to fix it.

I did my research that I need new server and management studio because whatever we used it's old. Here I am giving you info what we use. Can someone tell me if I upgrade to newer version of SQL Server and Management studio would be my problem resolved?
**We are using**

We are using MICROSOFT WINDOWS Server 2003r2 - Standard X64 Edition service pack 2

We are using SSMS as following version

```
MICROSOFTSQL Server 2005 - 9.00.5324.00 (X64) 
Aug 24 2012 18:28:47 
Copyright (c) 1988-2005 Microsoft Corporation
Standard Edition (64-bit) on WINDOWS NT 5.2 (Build 3790: Service Pack 2)
```

**I AM PLANNING TO UPGRADE**

I'm planning to upgrade from WINDOW sql server 2003 r2 with 2005 SQL Server Management Studio to WINDOWS sql server 2008r2 with 2012 SQL Server Management Studio so would be resolve my database corruption?

Comment: What are the symptoms of this corruption? How are you determining that corruption is occurring?

Comment: all the transaction log backups is failing. In the error log showing me that database corruption in the log file.

Comment: does the log are on a dedicated hard drive/volume ?

Comment: Yes it is dedicated hard drives. But my windows server and management studio is too old.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say from the information provided, but my instinct is that you have a storage issue--namely, that one or more of your hard drives are failing or failed.  Check your RAID status.

If the problem is storage failure, upgrading on the same hardware *will not* fix your problem.  As much as I hate to discourage anyone from upgrading off SQL 2005/Windows 2003, unless you're upgrading onto new hardware your efforts will be better spent figuring out what's actually causing the corruption.

(Sorry.)

Answer (score 0):

You can rebuild the log file by following query:

```
USE master
GO
ALTER DATABASE [Database_Name] SET EMERGENCY
GO
ALTER DATABASE [dbname] SET SINGLE_USER
GO
ALTER DATABASE [dbname] REBUILD LOG ON (NAME= logicalname, FILENAME=’Drive path to new file location\Log file name.ldf’) 
GO
DBCC CHECKDB ([dbname])
GO
ALTER DATABASE [dbname] SET MULTI_USER
GO
```